# Which sentence is correct to use with "rather"?

Tags: grammar

I have read that '**rather a/an+adjective+noun**' can be used with the meaning "**moderately**" or **"more than average**". Now I'm confused if I'm correct or not when writing the following sentences:

> 1.It's **a rather** boring movie, I don't recommend it.
>
> 2.It's **rather a** boring movie, I don't recommend it.

Which one is correct to use? Or both of them are correct?

Could we use '**rather'** without using "**a/an**" in the sentences ?

Comment: Both sentences are idiomatic; the second is slightly more _toffee-nosed._ (The first person pronoun is _always_ capitalized in English. In addition, we capitalize the first word in a sentence. You have asked 75 questions here; have you noticed the corrections made to them?)

Comment: I think I have correctted them

Comment: Well done...almost! Capitalization and punctuation are as important as grammar. Look closely at your question. You are to be congratulated for your efforts in  any case.

Comment: @P.E Dent,Can i use 'rather+adjectives+noun' for example. 1. It's rather boring movie.
2.we had to wait rather long time. again, if we use rather with verb, does it still give the sense of "moderately" in the sentences ?

Comment: You can indeed use 'rather+adjectives+noun', but don't neglect the article: _1. It's **a** rather boring movie. 2. We had to wait rather **a** long time._ It retains the sense of "moderately."

Answer (score 3):

With *a/an* article, the adverb of degree *rather* is usually used *before* it:

> rather + a/an + adjective + noun;

but "*a + rather + adjective + noun*" construction is also possible and is not less correct usage. ([the source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/rather))

Comment: I never knew that "rather an adjective noun" was correct, I've always used "a(n) rather adjective noun".

Comment: @Rompey, Can i use 'rather+adjectives+noun' for example. 1. It's rather boring movie.
2.we had to wait rather long time

Comment: No, you should follow one of the two patterns, i.e with the indefinite article.